# Sql sum function problem for multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create the sum of music duration for each of the artists in the new table.
I have two tables and I need to create sum function the third table. I am working on PHPadmin.
and I did this code but I do not know hos is it works anyone knows the solution?

```
SELECT

    SUM(Music Duration)(*)
FROM

    tbl_artist_list AS p,
    tbl_music_list AS c,
    tbl_single_query AS p_c
WHERE

    p.ID = p_c.Artist_ID AND c.ID = p_c.Music_ID
c.GROUP BY

   Music Duration
```

Comment: We need a little more clarity on your question. What is going wrong? Is your query not working? What did you expect to see? What are you seeing instead? With a little more details we might be able to help.

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid SQL, doesn't it give an error at all? Besides being a wrong SQL, what you are doing is a cross join and you are guaranteed to get wrong results if it ever worked. Ideally, you should do a sum() separately (in a subquery) and join the result with others. If you supply us some sample data we could give better answers. As of now, trying to write a correct query would depend on guesses only.

Comment: provide sample data and desired output , maybe prepare a fiddle